# how I can change the distance between text and tile

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

So I have two SwitchListTiles on my modal Page, and the problem is that the text doesn't fit into it. (it takes 3 lines, but should 1)
[How can I make it to be in one single line, without decreasing it's font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0BDY.png)

```
child: SwitchListTile(
        value: state.filter.flagId == null ? false : true,
        onChanged: (newValue) =>
            context.read<FilterBloc>().add(HotPressed(newValue)),
        title: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hotAdds.capitalize(),
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.dark50016.copyWith(),
        ),
        tileColor: FlutterFlowTheme.white,
        activeColor: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor,
        dense: true,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
      ),
```

I was thinking that the possible answer could be to decrease the distance between tile, but don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Just add "maxLines: 1" to Text widget

```
title: Text(
   AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hotAdds.capitalize(),
   style: FlutterFlowTheme.dark50016.copyWith(),
   maxLines: 1,
 ),
```

Comment: Sorry, but the other part of text will disappear, that won't work((

Comment: please look at the image I left

Answer (score 0):

There is default padding on the outer edges and also between the text and the switch. From what I can see the outer padding (the padding to the right of the switch and to the left of the text) defaults to 16. You can change this by adding contentPadding as an input to SwitchListTile and set the value to something smaller than 16:

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
```

But I'm not sure if you can change the padding between the text and the switch.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `text` widget to `Flexible` and `trim()` your text to avoid enter(\n) as string. `maxLines =1`.

```
title: Flexible(
              child: Text(
               AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hotAdds.capitalize().trim(),
                style: FlutterFlowTheme.dark50016.copyWith(),
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
```